# Multilabel classification with different number of classes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, multilabel

I have built a CNN with a final dense layer and a sigmoid activation to predict my ground truth. I have 10 variables. Three variables have three levels (classes) and 7 variables have two levels (classes). Right now I have built a model for each variable, i.e. ten models.

Is it also possible to build just one model and predict all 10 variables? I think the problem is that three variables have three levels. If all variables would only have two levels, I could just add 10 nodes and use sigmoid activation I think.

By the way, does it make more sense to build individual models (and also set parameters individual for each model) or to just train one model? I guess that individuals models are more powerful because parameters can be tuned individually.